# Catch a request after POST

Tags: cypress

I have a component in which a user can add a number of hours worked and post that to the server. For testing I want to remove the added hours so I can run the test again (the user cannot add hours on a day that already has hours).

There's a response on the request which has the id of the added hours. I can use a end point with that id to remove them. So the question is how do I gain access to the response of a request in Cypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  it('Removed saved hours', () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', 'api/v0/work-hours/?filter[job_id]=21173&filter[week_id]=202133').as('savedHours')

    cy.get('[data-cy=jobs]').children('div').first().click()

    cy.wait('@savedHours').then((res) => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'https://***/api/v0/work-hours',
        headers: {
          Authorization: res.request.headers.authorization,
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
          Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json'
        },
        body: {
          data: {
            data: {
              attributes: { ust_id: res.response.body.data[0].id },
              type: 'work_hours'
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

Got it working. What's important is that you first initiatie the interceptor, then do the call and then you can handle the data.